How do I encourage my baby lemon tree to grow up/strengthen instead of growing out?
Bought this lemon tree about 6 months back and haven’t seen too much change in it (providing we’re still in winter). Noticed today the outer branches seem to be growing slowly outward but the middle one has stayed much the same. Any tips on encoring a bit of strength/growth in the middle would be greatly appreciated!

@kevinskio why did you delete the answer to this post - it would seem to me to be a decent answer?

@davidgo What is this site’s policy on content generated by generative artificial intelligence tools?

Wouldn't trimming the side branches encourage the leader? Are you giving it full sun all day?
